# Updating Solana NFT metadata

Tags: solana, metaplex

Reaching out to the Solana NFT community for some help!

I have a collection that is hosted on arweave. The mint was through candy machine v2. However, only half of the intended supply was minted. This has caused confusion among holders who possess NFTs named above the max supply.

We would like to change collection metadata and port over to AWS to gain better control over this for the potential to add future utility.
I could not find info to help me achieve this, so any tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your NFTs are still mutable, to migrate from Arweave to AWS you will need to:

- Create AWS links for the JSON metadata of each NFT
- Update the URI for each NFT with the new URI

For the first step, you can just take the JSON files you used to create the NFTs originally and upload them to AWS. Once you have the links for each NFT you can use a tool like [Metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/update.html) to update the URIs. (See `update uri-all` command.)

Keep in mind:
Some attributes are duplicated between the external metadata and the on-chain metadata:

- name
- symbol
- creators
- seller_fee_basis_points

If you change any of those in the external metadata we recommend you change them in the on-chain metadata as well to keep the values synced. Metaplex is moving towards having as little redundancy as possible but in the meantime keep this in mind.

Comment: can i do this from code? are there any package similar to metaboss? i would like to automate this